# On emulator the widget appear but in device it didn't appear

Tags: flutter, dart

i use looping for my widget to appear with  `for (var item in surveyData)`

this is the full code

```
 body: ListView(
    children: [
      // Header Text
      Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(24, 24, 24, 0),
        child: Text(
          widget.surveyPages['header_label'],
          style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
            fontSize: 16,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Column(
        children: [
          for (var item in surveyData)
            AdditionalForm(
              questionLabel: item['label'],
              questionType: item['type'],
            ),
        ],
      ),

      SizedBox(height: 30),
    ],
  ),
```

on emulator

[image]

on device

[image]

Comment: This gray area is the equivalent of the red  error screen in debug mode, so your widget is probably throwing an error. Can you run on the device in debug mode and see the error and add it to your question please?

Comment: there is no error in emulator

Comment: I know, I'm asking you to debug on the device instead of emulator

Comment: but im not using my device as debug or something i just install apk in my device

Comment: Can you please run it on debug on the device?

Comment: i really do not understand do you mean debug on my phone or device on my computer that i use to run the code ?

Answer (score 0):

YOU KNOW WHAT ??? IT'S BECAUSE MY TEXTFIELD WRAPPED BY EXPANDED !!! :'( spend allday fixing this